Why did Python designers decide not to declare vars?
In Python when you want a local variable, you just assign to it x = 10.
In most modern languages you declare local vars (regardless of type):

JavaScript: let/const/var
Swift: let/var
Kotlin: val/var
Rust: let
Go: var
...

Is there any documentation as to why this approach was taken in Python? I couldn't find anything that explains this decision.
In Python 3 they broke a lot of the syntax, so I take it they still thought/think it's a good idea.
To clarify: I'm not asking for pros and cons here. Just wondering why Python designers made this specific choice.

There are several languages that don't require variable declarations: JavaScript, Python, Ruby.  The benefits are simplicity, flexibility and less code boilerplate.  The tradeoffs are lack of type safety, less readability, difficulty in debugging and performance.  Although you didn't ask for pros and cons, these are likely the considerations the Python designers considered when making the choice.

If you dig a little further you find out that Python doesn't declare variables in no small part because it's a dynamically-typed language, so it's not really possible to know the type of a variable ahead of time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781454

@RobertHarvey In JS you declare vars using const/let/var. If you don't, they go to the global object.

If you look into the history of Python, you will find it was influenced by the design of ABC which does not require variable declarations.

You might want to check out this article: https://inference-review.com/article/the-origins-of-python

I can flip your question around: what benefit would there have been to add declarations to Python 3?

You might like to read https://www.artima.com/articles/the-making-of-python, which doesn't mention declaration specifically, but think about how including declarations would have helped, rather than what its lack hinders.

@chepner well, there's at least one benefit: a = b statement becomes context independent. At the moment it is not, which is both harder to read/analyze by human and tools.

@freakish I'm not sure what you mean. One difference I am aware of is that a typo makes the difference between changing an existing variable and creating a new variable.

@chepner the a = b statement is ambiguous. Am I creating a new variable or assigning to existing one? It is impossible to say without context, without knowing entire source code in given file. With var (or equivalent) keyword it is clear.

@freakish don’t be silly. Obviously you’re testing for equality.

Does this answer your question?

@freakish this is the clear disadvantage, and I can attest that it is not theoretical.  I've been burned by this more than once.  It also creates the need for global and local declaration warts which is pretty ironic, I think.

@JimmyJames Why do you think they are more "wartish" than a general keyword for declaration? Either you default to a local variable and use global/nonlocal to  override that, or you default to global (or nonlocal: which one?) and explicitly declare local variables. Further, since there are no sub-function-level scopes, there's no further possibility of shadowing.

People have different philosophies on what a programming language should look like, and how one should express ideas in a language. E.g., there are people who love C++ and all the power and fine control that comes with it, and there are people who think C++ is "an insult to the human brain". Python's philosophy is leaning more towards simplicity, conciseness, readability, and a certain kind of elegance of expression; the designers probably felt a special keyword for declarations was unnecessary fluff/noise.

@chepner Well, for one it's awkward to declare variables in a narrower scope than that of the variable.  It's a sort of weird non-declaration as well, an "I am not defining this here" statement. More practically, it's really easy to forget to do it and have no clear error message.  I love most things about Python but the lack of a distinct name creation syntax for variables is not one of them.

Not only Python makes it possible to create a variable by using variable assignment. Ruby and Bash are two other languages that use the same approach.
The benefit of not having an additional keyword—and additional step of declaring a variable—is simplicity. This simplicity is particularly important when using REPL, where typing less is really important. It is also important to think about the “dynamic” nature of the environment, where a variable can freely change its nature: two lines before, x was storing a dictionary of files and their sizes, but now, x is the contents of a file, and two lines after that, x may be the exit code of the last command. One particular case which is quite frequent is when you type an expression where a variable assignment is made, and then find that you made a typo. No problem: you can type ↑, change the instruction, and submit it again.
Compare it with JavaScript. I stopped counting the number of times where I was playing with the in-browser console, typing, say, let disabled = elements.filter(x => x.enabled), just to discover a second later that I made a typo: it should have been x => !x.enabled. If I type ↑, add the missing exclamation point, and resubmit, I would receive the error “Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let disabled.” I have to go back to the beginning of the line and remove let  as well.
As JavaScript wasn't designed with REPL in mind (Node.js and its REPL capabilities through command line came much, much later; same for in-browser consoles), the designers of JavaScript decided that this was not important. Also, very likely, the designers of JavaScript didn't have the mindset of a minimalist approach that was used in Python and Ruby. This may be considered a bad thing, or a good thing. For instance, what those two lines of Ruby code do?
SomeNumber = 42
hello = 'Hello, World!'

For someone who is not familiar with Ruby's conventions, it won't be obvious that the first line creates a constant, whereas the second one—a variable. JavaScript's explicitness pays the price of more typing, but is clearer:
const someNumber = 45;
let hello = 'Hello, World!';

In the same way, having a clear variable declaration (distinct from variable assignment) has its benefits too. One of the examples has to do with scopes. Imagine the following piece of code:
def demo():
    ...  # Some logic here, given that `x` is not assigned here.
    print(x)

Suppose the code works as expected. Now you add a tiny little line of code:
def demo():
    ...  # Some logic here, given that `x` is not assigned here.
    if something:
        x = x * percentage
    print(x)

You run this code, and when something evaluates to True, you are welcomed with this error: “UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'x' where it is not associated with a value.”
It appears that x was actually assigned in the parent scope (outside demo), and x = ... introduced a local variable x with the value set to x * percentage, where x is the local variable, and not the parent one. With a language that has variable declarations, this wouldn't have happened.

Coming at this from a UX angle, there is no need for explicit variable declaration in any language.
A compiler can easily infer that the first reference to a variable can either automatically be declared (if it's an assignment, using the type of the value being assigned in statically typed languages) or is wrong (when it's trying to use a variable without any prior assignment).
The benefit of forcing developers to explicitly declare a variable is to force the developer to be aware of which variables they're working with, and to prevent scenarios where a developer mistypes an existing variable name (or refers to a variable that's out of scope) and have the compiler not notice this because it just blindly assumes that the developer intended for this to be a completely new variable unrelated to an already existing one.
This is a subjective call whether you'd prefer to not have to declare things explicitly vs having the compiler check your consistency in referencing variables. Clearly the Python language designers felt differently from the others.
